# Ignore invalid certificates in Node.js native fetch

Tags: node.js, fetch-api

How do I make the Node.js (version 20) built-in global `fetch` function ignore invalid SSL certificates?

I searched, and the information out there is for `undici` or `node-fetch`. Is there no option to do it with the native `fetch`?

Comment: The native fetch _is_ undici (see e.g. https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/contributing/maintaining/maintaining-http.md#client-apis), did you try applying that solution?

Comment: I was using `request`, till its home page went red and then had to move to `got`. I waited for Nodejs 18 to migrate out to use the native `fetch`. As it turned out, installing `undici` added two vulnerabilities, one High and one Critical. Fortunately `audit fix` seemed to remove them.

Comment: Again, the native `fetch` _is `undici`_; it's vendored into Node.js itself. But the full API isn't exposed, hence you'll sometimes need to install it as a dependency. And if `npm audit fix` worked immediately after `npm install undici` then those vulnerabilities logically weren't introduced by that installation - unless you `--force` it, `fix` can only apply updates that were already valid according to semver, installing would use the latest such packages already.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to connect a fresh agent with your preferred configuration?

As mentioned bellow...

```
const https = require('https');

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    });

await fetch('https://example.com', {
  dispatcher: httpsAgent,
});
```

Comment: This method didn't work for me. I had to install `undici`, which I was trying to avoid, and use this: https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/1489#issuecomment-1543856261